# Spark is not use all configured storage memory capacity

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, memory-management, apache-spark-sql

My task in spark uses images data for prediction I am working on a spark cluster standalone but I have an issue utilizing all the available memory capacity as here all available memory is 2.7 GB (coming from a memory executor that is configured 5 GB *0.6 *0.9= 2.7 it's okay ) but the usage memory is only 342 MB after that value my spark session being crashed and I did not know why this specific value!

I test my application on local and on a standalone cluster mode in addition whatever the memory executor configured value the limit of memory value for execution will be 342 MB. and here as shown my data size of 290691 KB led to the crash of my spark session and it works fine if I decrease the number of images

as follows screenshot issue:

This output error crashed with a data size of 290691 KB

[image: this output error and crashed with data size 290691 KB]

Here my spark UI Storage Memory did not exceed 342 MB

[image: my spark UI Storage Memory did not exceed 342 MB]

so is there any advice or what is the correct spark configuration?

Comment: Can you add your cluster configuration i.e. number of workers and their cores/memory

Comment: yes, I tested on local and on the cluster but still have the same issue only (342 mega is used from available memory) as in my question, the only configuration parameter is {spark.driver.memory  5g} working on local mode.
and in addition here spark UI in cluster 2 worker [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VQgHObfujtU6LNc87soGD4zuhr4DWk34/view?usp=sharing) 

with this configuration [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g9SEuv5AncL6-4rL4zPFNKrmtsVkaj46/view?usp=sharing)
num_executors=2, executors_cores=2,driver_cores=2,executor_memory="3g",driver_memory="3g"

Comment: Can you please provide Spark UI home screenshot (the one you have provided above are of job specific details)?

Comment: sure, I am also upgrading my spark version to 2.4.8 but still, this issue exists, and here is my spark UI screenshot[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GOuVBpmoBManb28vtKVueqi2O0TALn9_/view?usp=sharing), [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YNPN8fRbv9x_N7Bg3USnr92Mw6qtJOvI/view?usp=sharing) and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AKH6hflBljoWkEk7lIBXyzmX4AY87izC/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: These are again of job specific! Send landing page of `master:8080` where you see Spark cluster related sections like Workers, Running Applications, Running Drivers, Completed Applications etc!

Comment: master:8080 or even 8081 are not reachable, so what does this mean Sorry I am still new in this area.

all my spark confs file:-
spark.master                     spark://master:7077
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.eventLog.dir               file:///usr/local/spark/tmp
spark.driver.memory                 5g
spark.serializer                 org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dkey=value -Dnumbers="one two three"

Answer (score 0):

It's a warning, initially.

The general gist here is that you need to repartition to get more, but smaller size partitions, so as to get more parallelism and higher throughput. You can find many such issues out there on the Internet.